# How to get dropdown selected value when onchange event fires

Tags: jquery

I have a table and there are two dropdowns in every row of two column. Those dropdowns are `cboState` and `cboCity`. When the user selects state then I need to show `cboState`'s dropdown's selected value and text in alert and also I have to find `cboCity` in same table row and get its selected value and text if any.

I wrote this code but it is not working

```
$("#gridContent .webgrid-table tbody [id*='cboState']").change(function () {
    alert('State ' + $(this).tex() + ' ' + $(this).val());
    //var cboCity = $(this).closest('tr').find("select[id*='cboCity']");
    //alert('City ' + cboCity.tex() + ' ' + cboCity.val());
});
```

Comment: So what is not working in the code that is commented out?

Comment: you have typo here ``$(this).tex()`` it must be text()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#gridContent .webgrid-table tbody [id*='cboState']").change(function () {
    alert('State ' + $(this).children(":selected").text() + ' ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: for showing text u used `children(":selected")` but for value u did not use `children(":selected")` why ?

Comment: because when you need <select> value, you just use val(). there's no text in <select> element, only in <option> element inside <select>

Comment: value and text both are in option element. so why we need to use children(":selected") to get text but different approach taken for val()?

Comment: children(":selected") used to select only selected option. if not, there will be array of options